# MethodNotAllowedHttpException The DELETE method is not supported in Laravel

Tags: laravel-8

I created a project using Laravel 8, and I made a blade/view to delete records from the database, but the error appeared when I clicked on the delete button.

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
> The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> POST

**Blade/view**

```
<form action="{{ route('destroy', $steps->id) }}" method="POST">
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="">Show</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('steps',$steps->id) }}">Edit</a>
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function destroy(Step $step)
{
    $step->delete();

    return redirect()->route('show');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('destroy', [LinkController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy');
```

Comment: Hello, any answer please

Answer (score 0):

You Need to send id in your route to declare model binding in your function so the write code is:

```html
Route::post('destroy/{step}', [LinkController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy');
```